# Populating a variable with -ErrorVariable

Tags: powershell

I'm using powershell 4.0, and I'm trying to use the -ErrorVariable parameter to populate a variable so that I can check the .count property and see if an error occurred in a previous step. I've tried to use the guide [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/11/03/erroraction-and-errorvariable.aspx) but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have this portion of the script that calls an xml file

```
$getError = $null
[xml]$a = Get-Content -ErrorVariable $getError .\test.xml
Write-Host $getError.count
```

I have the step pull in a malformed xml file, but the valute of `$getError` remains $null even if the step fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting anything because the Get-Content succeeds.  What fails is the subsequent cast of the return to [XML], but you can't caputure that with ErrorVariable.
Does this work for you?

```
$getError = @()
try { [xml]$a = Get-Content  $getError .\test.xml -ErrorAction Stop }
 catch { $getError += $Error[0] }
Write-Host $getError.count
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to what @mjolinor said, you're passing the *value* of $getError to the -ErrorVariable parameter.  To use -ErrorVariable, you need to pass the *name* of the variable which doesn't include the $.

```
$getError = $null
[xml]$a = Get-Content -ErrorVariable getError .\test.xml
Write-Host $getError.count
```